# select statement using inner query comparing multiple values of same column

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables and I need a query like below

```
select t1.username,count(*)  
from <table1>,<table2> 
where <table1.username> in(select username from <table2>)---this is wrong query.
```

I have given just to show the way how I need

How can I compare a column value of table1 with all values of a specific column in table2

when I try this it is showing error inner query returning multiple values

Comment: You need to show the table structures along the expected output.

Comment: yes, i need to show. but it is private and i am not having time to prepare model structure

Answer (score 0):

This should work using a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select t1.username, count(*)
from table1 t1 
    join table2 t2 on t1.username = t2.username
group by t1.username
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are after:

```
select t1.username,count(*)  as cnt
from table1 t1
where table1.username in (select username from table2)
group by t1.username
```

Comment: FYI: This will not give you the same count as using a `JOIN`.  This will only count the number of records in `table1`.  With that said, hard to completely understand what OP is after here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an inner join, which will give you only records that have a username that matches in table1 and table2

```
select t1.username, count(*)
from table1 t1 
    INNER join table2 t2 on t1.username = t2.username
group by t1.username
```

If you want all records from table1 regardless of a match in table 2, you want an outer join:

```
select t1.username, count(*)
from table1 t1 
    LEFT OUTER join table2 t2 on t1.username = t2.username
group by t1.username
```

Edited to explain group by:

Group by means that you are using an aggregate function (the count(*)) with a non-aggregate column (t1.username) and it will combine rows that have the same non-aggregate column(t1.username).  This allows you to use an aggregate column and a non-aggregate column.